# QGIS georeferenced image does not apear in the map area

Tags: qgis, georeferencing

I'm having issues with some georeferenced images in QGIS 2.10.1-Pisa.

I generally georeference PDF's of new land subdivisions over aerial photos to get the layout of the new subdivision, generally it works fine. Occasionally I go through the process of georeferencing the image and when finished the overlay doesn't show up on the map area.

When I look at the layer property the overlay shows as a thumbnail but not on the screen.

All that shows on the screen are the little red dots indicating the reference points I use to georeference the overlay so I assume the CRS settings are correct as the dots appear in the right places.

I have tried most settings that I can think of however I can't get the image to appear.

Comment: Did you try saving the georeferenced image in a different file format?

Comment: Can you add screenshots of the GCP table, and the georeferencing settings dialogue?

Comment: Maybe you have activated the scale dependent visibility? This makes the data only visible from a certain scale. So when you are zoomed out too much you won't see your picture. This option can be accessed on the first tab of the layer-properties.